# Nuxtjs version 3 gives Server Side Rendering Error

Tags: nuxt.js, server-side-rendering, nuxtjs3

I installed Nuxt 3 latest to start understanding what it can do.

However when I run

```
yarn dev
```

I get this Error after Vite warm up, Vite server built and Nitro built.
The page I see is empty but wehn I refresh, I still get me say "hello World".

Can anyone help?

Thanks

```
Server Side Rendering Error: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_VALUE]: The argument 'path' must be a string or Uint8Array without null bytes. Received '/Users/xxxxxx/vue_js_v3/nuxt_3/nuxt3-redo/\x00virtual:/Users/xxxxxx/vue_js_v3/nuxt_3/nuxt3-redo/.nuxt/css.mjs'
    at statSync (fs.js:1124:10)
    at tryStatSync (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:109:13)
    at finalizeResolution (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:301:17)
    at moduleResolve (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:731:10)
    at Loader.defaultResolve [as _resolve] (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:842:11)
    at Loader.resolve (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:89:40)
    at Loader.getModuleJob (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:242:28)
    at Loader.import (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:177:28)
    at importModuleDynamically (internal/modules/esm/translators.js:114:35)
    at exports.importModuleDynamicallyCallback (internal/process/esm_loader.js:30:14) {
  code: 'ERR_INVALID_ARG_VALUE'
}
```

Comment: Hi, could you please share a [repro] or your configuration + steps done so far? Hard to debug with just this.

Comment: my config is:
iMac on MacOS Big Sur 11.6
the Nuxt install was with the Nuxt CLI v3.0.0-27235451.ece0e01
package.json only has dev-dependencies. : Nuxt3: latest
no personalisation done yet on the file structure as problem occured with out-of-the-box install

Comment: Project configuration. Also, a [repro] is still the best here.

Comment: Hi, just to be sure, I started another install with nothing but the install instructions from the Nuxt3 website and the problem persists. Thanks for helping!

Comment: Totally works on my side tbh.

Comment: That's good for you. But it does not help me!

Comment: I cannot help neither if you don't share any code or repro. I can't just guess what is the issue by your words as of right now.